# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cos\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}2}{\sin\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}2}-4\sqrt{x+1}\cos(\sqrt{x+1})-\sin(\sqrt{x+1})$

Tags: geometry, limits, trigonometry

I need help with some limit I got stuck with.
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)} - 4\sqrt{x+1}\cos\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)-\sin\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)$$

When I calculate this for large numbers, it seem like it tends toward zero. As an attempt to prove it, I squared the equation in WolframAlpha and after some simplifying:
$$\left(\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)} - 4\sqrt{x+1}\cos\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)-\sin\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)\right)^2 =  \frac{1+\cos\left(2\sqrt{x+1}\right)}{2}\left(4\sqrt{x+1}-\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\right)^2$$

noticing that:
$$0 \leq \frac{1+\cos\left(2\sqrt{x+1}\right)}{2} \leq 1$$

so that means the above limit is related to this new limit:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} 4\sqrt{x+1}-\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}}{2}\right)$$
which also seem to tend toward zero but don't know how to prove it, any help?

Comment: What let you suppose that limit exists?

Comment: it's my conjecture and the secend limit have a direct relation to it.

Comment: so i need who help me with it.

Comment: Could you share your evaluation by WA?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}2=u, u\to 0$$
$$a=\sqrt{x+1}=u+\frac{1}{4u}$$
$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)} - 4\sqrt{x+1}\cos\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)-\sin\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)=$$ $$=\frac{\cos(a-u)}{\sin u}-4a\cos a-\sin a=
\frac{\cos a (\cos u- 4a \sin u)}{\sin u}=(\cot u-4a)\cos a;$$
$$\cot u-4a=\cot u-4u-\frac1{u}=O(u)\to 0$$

Comment: Very nice way to handle it!

Answer (score 1):

With reference with the last limit, we have that

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}{2}=\frac{1}{2\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}\right)}$$

therefore

$$\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}}{2}\right)=\frac1{\tan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}}{2}\right)}=\frac1{\frac{1}{2\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}\right)}+O(x\sqrt x)}=4\sqrt x+O\left(\frac1x\right)$$

and then

$$ 4\sqrt{x+1}-\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}}{2}\right)=4\sqrt{x+1}-4\sqrt x+O\left(\frac1x\right) \to 0$$

Comment: would you please try to exlpain what you did after 1/tan()

Comment: i know what a O() is but i need you to explain the two steps after 1/tan()

Comment: We have used that $\tan t=t+O(t^3)$ for $t\to 0$